I encountered an error when executing lerna init
Cannot initialize lerna because your package manager has not been configured to use workspaces, and you have not explicitly specified any packages to operate on.
how can i solve this problem?I don't quite understand why this problem occurs

You need to configure workspaces which is different depending on which package manager you decide to use. For more info on how to setup a workspace, choose the best option that fits your need:

npm 7+ workspaces
Yarn classic workspaces
Yarn 2+ workspaces
pnpm workspaces

